# Which backup package can meet these requirements?

Tags: backup, cron

I am looking for a decent, simple to use snapshot package.  It should accomplish the following:

- store several profiles for different jobs (ex. /home part, /root part, )
- linkable to cron for daily execution
- sync changes from source part. to dest part. (separate part, same drive)
- restore files, or entire, from within os or live usb/cd.

What backup package can accomplish this simply?

Comment: Have a look at CrashPlan, although it doesn't do No.3 for you...

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a simple bash script to run `rsync` for each type of backup you need. Nothing could be faster to run, and setting the options in any GUI backup utility is going to be about as complicated as a bash script running rsync.

A quick google search will find you a few good [tutorials with examples](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/automating-a-daily-rsync-backup). I've got three running as cron jobs on my desktop.